# Firebase Functions extracting Token

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Trying to grab my FCM token from my Cloud Firestore using Firebase Function

my function code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificationToFCMToken = functions.firestore.document('Posts/{likes}').onWrite(async (event) => {
    const title = event.after.get('title');
    const content = event.after.get('likes');
    let userDoc = await admin.firestore().doc('Users').get();
    let fcmToken = userDoc.get('{token}');

    var message = {
        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: "you have a new like",
        },
        token: fcmToken,
    }

    let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
    console.log(response);
});
```

My Firestore

Posts:

[image: Posts]

Users:

[image: Users]

if I manually add the token everything works but just send every "like" to one device, my goal is to send a link to only the owner of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin's answer is correct, but it seems that the `ref` field is of type Reference, see the slash at the beginning, plus the error you get.

So, if this assumption is correct, you should use the [`path`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html) property, as follows (adapting Martin's code):

```
let userRef = event.after.get('ref'); // obviously the path is mandatory ...
let userDoc = await admin.firestore().doc(userRef.path).get(); // then this should match
let token = userDoc.get('token'); // and the token should be accessible
```

---

In addition, in order to correctly [manage the life cycle of your Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?authuser=0), you should do, at the end:

```
let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
console.log(response);
return null;
```

or simply

```
return admin.messaging().send(message);
```

Comment: Thank you so for your time Renaud, just deployed and  worked perfectly. 

Tomorrow challenge is to workout why it sends a notification on title change too.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably more alike this:

```
let userRef = event.after.get('ref'); // obviously the path is mandatory ...
let userDoc = await admin.firestore().doc(userRef).get(); // then this should match
let token = userDoc.get('token'); // and the token should be accessible
```

Add logging to see what you get: `functions.logger.info(' ' + JSON.stringify(event));` ...viewable at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query. When listening for `Posts/{likes}` you'd likely need an additional query - and when listening for `Posts`, you'd need to determine changes. Getting access to `ref` is required to make the subsequent query work.

Comment: Thank you Martin, just deployed that and got the following:

Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.